# Tool to synchronize PostgreSQL DDL and data databases

Tags: postgresql, data-synchronization

We have several developers who each have a local database for testing. We often make DDL and/or data changes to the master database that we need to replicate to each development machine. The framework we use allows us to use the concept of migrations, which cover 95% of the use cases. However, in some cases we are in need of a simple refresh.

The procedure now is to dump the schema on the master, copy it to each developer's local machine, drop the schema from their database, and reload it from the dump. This is slow, and we would like to be able to compare the two databases more directly and only transfer/execute what has changed. Most tools that I've found (such as SLONY) don't handle DDL changes because they rely on triggers. I found this product: http://www.datanamic.com/schemadiff-for-postgresql/index.html, but it seems to be built for a Windows GUI only.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Which language do you use for developing your apps?

Comment: Primarily PHP, though I am open to any languages that run on a *nix platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some tools that have been around for a while, though I have not used any of them:

- https://github.com/jmafc/Pyrseas
- http://www.andromeda-project.org/
- https://labs.omniti.com/labs/pgtreats/wiki/getddl

I have a feeling there is at least one more floating around, but a quick search didn't trigger any other links for me.

Comment: I'm surprised I didn't find any of these in my search. Pyrseas looks to be particularly useful, if paired with another tool that synchronizes data (of which there appear to be plenty).

Comment: I've seen the author of Pyrseas in the Postgresql mailing lists a few times and he seems to be a pretty sharp guy. I think he has contributed to patches to the core Postgresql codebase too.